Issue with Facebook authentication: "Feature unavailable - Facebook Login is currently unavailable for this application"
I've encountered an issue with integrating Facebook authentication into my application https://www.aswaktinghir.com/. Whenever I attempt to authenticate through Facebook, I receive the error message: "Feature unavailable - Facebook Login is currently unavailable for this application because we are updating additional application information. Please try again later."
After some investigation, I believe the solution lies in changing the permissions for email and public_profile from standard access to advanced access. However, upon making this change in the API calls, they become deactivated as shown in the screenshot attached. Despite this change, the error persists.
How can I resolve this issue and successfully authenticate users through Facebook in my application?
Screenshot: images
